# How to synchronize Selection, Sorting and Filtering between two JTables

Tags: java, swing, jtable, filtering, selection

I've been trying to get two tables that are basically completly synchronized in both sorting and filtering (RowSorter) and selection (SelectionModel). In order to achieve that, I made two classes.
Those are wrapper classes for the `SelectionModel` and the `RowSorter`. They are basically just delegating each public method that mutates state. Below you can see shortened versions of them that only contain one overwritten setter. However, all the others are overwritten too. I don't wanna bloat the question too much.

The `MirrorableRowSorter` (shortend):

```java
public class MirrorableRowSorter<M extends TableModel> extends TableRowSorter<M>
{
  private MirrorableRowSorter<M> delegate;

  /**
   * @param delegate the delegate to set
   */
  public void setDelegate( MirrorableRowSorter<M> delegate )
  {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public void setSortKeys( List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys )
  {
    if ( delegate != null )
    {
      delegate.setSortKeysNonDelegating( sortKeys );
    }
    super.setSortKeys( sortKeys );
  }

  private void setSortKeysNonDelegating( List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys )
  {
    super.setSortKeys( sortKeys );
  }

  //... other methods
}
```

The `MirrorableSelectionModel` (shortend):

```java
public class MirrorableSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel
{
  private MirrorableSelectionModel delegate = null;

  /**
   * @param delegate the delegate to set
   */
  public void setDelegate( final MirrorableSelectionModel delegate )
  {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public void setSelectionInterval( final int index0, final int index1 )
  {
    if ( delegate != null )
    {
      delegate.setSelectionIntervalNonDelegating( index0, index1 );
    }
    super.setSelectionInterval( index0, index1 );
  }

  private void setSelectionIntervalNonDelegating( final int index0, final int index1 )
  {
    super.setSelectionInterval( index0, index1 );
  }

  //... other methods
```

There's always a delegating and a non-delegating method. I've done this in order to avoid Ping-Pong between the two objects.

I then wrote a little example with two tables:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;

public class ExampleMirroredTables
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    final JTable tableOne = new JTable( new Object[][]{
        new Object[]{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "3", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "4", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "5", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "6", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "7", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "8", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "9", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" }
    }, new Object[]{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" } );
    final JTable tableTwo = new JTable( new Object[][]{
        new Object[]{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "3", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "4", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "5", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "6", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "7", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "8", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "9", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
        new Object[]{ "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" }
    }, new Object[]{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" } );


    final MirrorableSelectionModel mirrorModelOne = new MirrorableSelectionModel();
    final MirrorableSelectionModel mirrorModelTwo = new MirrorableSelectionModel();
    mirrorModelOne.setDelegate( mirrorModelTwo );
    mirrorModelTwo.setDelegate( mirrorModelOne );
    tableOne.setSelectionModel( mirrorModelOne );
    tableTwo.setSelectionModel( mirrorModelTwo );

    final MirrorableRowSorter mirrorSorterOne = new MirrorableRowSorter();
    final MirrorableRowSorter mirrorSorterTwo = new MirrorableRowSorter();
    mirrorSorterOne.setDelegate( mirrorSorterTwo );
    mirrorSorterTwo.setDelegate( mirrorSorterOne );
    mirrorSorterOne.setModel( tableOne.getModel() );
    mirrorSorterTwo.setModel( tableTwo.getModel() );
    tableOne.setRowSorter( mirrorSorterOne );
    tableTwo.setRowSorter( mirrorSorterTwo );

    JButton filterButton = new JButton( "Filter randomize" );
    AtomicBoolean even = new AtomicBoolean( true );
    filterButton.addActionListener( __ ->
    {
      even.set( !even.get() );
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( tableOne.getSelectedRows() ) );
      mirrorSorterTwo.setRowFilter( new RowFilter()
      {
        @Override
        public boolean include( Entry entry )
        {
          final int moduloResult = ((Integer) entry.getIdentifier()) % 2;
          return even.get() ? moduloResult == 0 : moduloResult != 0;
        }
      } );
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( tableOne.getSelectedRows() ) );
    } );

    frame.add( filterButton, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    frame.add( tableOne, BorderLayout.WEST );
    frame.add( new JLabel( "  THE MIRROR  " ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
    frame.add( tableTwo, BorderLayout.EAST );

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

As you'll be able to see if you use the selection, it will always mirror perfectly. However, if you now hit the filter button at the top after selecting all rows (Ctrl+A), out of the 10 selected rows, only the indices `0` and `1` will be kept. I would like to not only keep the filtered 5 out of the 10 selected, but also keep the other (now hidden) ones selected and still see the selection after changing the filter again. The reason for this is, that we have a JTable that mimics a tree. If we collapse an item in that tree and having the parent and it's children selected beforehand, we want them to still be selected after expanding the parent again. I thought that this is possible, since this appears to work when using the mirrored selection model, but I am unsure why.

I am not quite sure whether what I am trying to achieve is possible at all, if yes, I don't know whether I am taking the right approach.

Here are all files as a gist: https://gist.github.com/Bios-Marcel/ada8781c79b7f13b3e0b3d8486462913

If there's an existing thing (library) for synchronizing tables, I'd be willing to look into that as well.

Comment: Hi Marcel. I think you were going to update this question - do you plan to still do that, or do you not need more answers?

Comment: I kinda got intangled in other things, therefore I am not focusing on this problem for now. In case I do focus on it again and I find a soluton, I'll 100% post it here.

Comment: No worries. If you need to come back to this, ping me and I can help getting it opened again.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a model can be shared by multiple views.

```
tableTwo.setSelectionModel( tableOne.getSelectionModel() );
```

Not sure what would happen if the number of rows in each model was different.

However, the same approach can't be used for sorting/filtering, since you are using multiple TableModels.

So maybe a different approach is to have a single TableModel with 20 columns. Then you would have two tables with 2 different views of the model.

The first table would display the first 10 columns and the second table would display the last 10 columns.

Basic proof of concept:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableSync extends JPanel
{
    public TableSync()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        String[] columnNames = {"Date", "String", "Integer", "Boolean"};

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {new Date(), "A", Integer.valueOf(1), Boolean.TRUE },
            {new Date(), "B", Integer.valueOf(2), Boolean.FALSE},
            {new Date(), "C", Integer.valueOf(12), Boolean.TRUE },
            {new Date(), "D", Integer.valueOf(5124), Boolean.FALSE}
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = createTableModel(data, columnNames);

        JTable table1 = new JTable( model );
        table1.removeColumn( table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2) );
        table1.removeColumn( table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2) );

        JTable table2 = new JTable( model );
        table2.removeColumn( table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0) );
        table2.removeColumn( table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0) );

        table2.setSelectionModel( table1.getSelectionModel() );

        table1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table2.setRowSorter( table1.getRowSorter() );

        table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table1.getPreferredSize());
        add(new JScrollPane(table1), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        table2.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table2.getPreferredSize());
        add(new JScrollPane(table2), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    private DefaultTableModel createTableModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames)
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers and editors to be used based on Class

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null)
                        return o.getClass();
                }

                return Object.class;
            }
        };

        return model;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableSync");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableSync() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my question wasn't specific enough. I'll try to give a more thorough explanation tomorrow. In the past I've encountered problems when trying to share SelectionModel and RowSorter. Therefore I tried to go for a mirror approach, which worked better. My only problem is really the loss of selection when adding a filter and removing it again. And I am not actually trying to mirror tables, I just thought that's enough for an minimal example. I am actually making a rowheader with different columns that don't display fields of the beans, but dynamic data that differs based on where it's used.

Comment: *I've encountered problems when trying to share SelectionModel and RowSorter.* - appears to work here. *I think my question wasn't specific enough* agreed.  Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: So, I have taken a look at this again. And the thing I was struggling with, was mostly the row sorter destroying the selection when there's a filter. I wrote a workaround for this, where I preserve the selection model, replace it with a temporary throwaway one, refresh the sorter and then insert the old selection model again. Pretty weird, but that did the trick for me.